# Assignment shorthand with anonymous / arrow function callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

I have this code sample:

```
 before('get all users', h => {
    return getAllUsers().then(function (users) {
      return h.supply.users = users;
    });
  });
```

I am looking for some shorthand, is this the best I can do?

```
 before('get all users', h => {
    return getAllUsers().then(v => (h.supply.users = v));
 });
```

I am thinking that maybe there is some alternate assignment trick we can use.

Comment: `before('get all users', h => getAllUsers().then(v => (h.supply.users = v)));`

Comment: Does `getAllUsers()` return more than one value? If so, it seems wasteful to keep reassigning a different value to `h.supply.users`, unless that's a "setter" property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in a single line

```
   before('get all users', h => getAllUsers().then(v => h.supply.users=v));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could create a helper function, something like this:

```
const assign = function(v1){
    return function(v2){
       return v1 = v2;
    }
};


before('get all users', h => getAllUsers().then(assign(h.supply.users)));
```

**// untested**

not a great solution as it might break some `Object.defineProperty` hooks, etc. Would not recommend doing this. :)